# iOS tableview: hide vertical section legend

Tags: objective-c, ios5, scrollbar, tableview

I'm trying to hide the vertical legend that normally displays the first char of a section in a tableview. The problem is that because of a hierarchical structure each category (or section) begins with `tu-graz`. In fact, the tableview extracts the first char of the section name and builds up a scroll-bar. But this ends up in just one char in the bar (the `t`) and doesn't make sense...

I think the following screenshot describes better what I mean:

[image: screenshot of my issue]

Is there a simple way to hide this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution. Simply return `nil` from the following method:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return nil;
}
```